# UIView animation being called twice, canceling out the animation

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, uiviewanimation

I have a UIView animation bringing a UIView from the left onto the screen, the method is being triggered so quickly in rapid succession from the bar code scanning engine that the method is being triggered then triggered again so it goes back off of the screen.

```
-(IBAction)showDetailModeView
{
    if (detailModeViewON==FALSE)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        [detailModeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        detailModeViewON=TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        [detailModeView setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 568)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self stopScanning];
        scannedONCE = FALSE;
        detailModeViewON=FALSE;
    }
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

is there some way I can basically say if this method was called within the last 5 seconds, don't do anything.

pseudo code

```
-(IBAction)showDetailModeView
{

if(UIVIEW animation was triggered longer than 5 seconds ago)
{ 
    if (detailModeViewON==FALSE)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        [detailModeView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 568)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        detailModeViewON=TRUE;
    }
    else
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"move buttons" context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:.3];
        [detailModeView setFrame:CGRectMake(-320, 0, 320, 568)];
        [UIView commitAnimations];

        [self stopScanning];
        scannedONCE = FALSE;
        detailModeViewON=FALSE;
    }
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edited to add that you should be using block based animations such as;

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
                 animations:(void (^)(void))animations
                 completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion];
```

You can find a lot of examples of this around here.

A lot of the time you need to disallow a transition while one is happening. set the gesture.enabled to NO, for example, and back to YES in the animation's completion block, or use a boolean that you set to NO before the animation begins and set it back to YES in the completion block. Then have a check to see what that boolean is before calling the animation.

These kinds of things are very common in UI implementation. Otherwise you can end up with a lot of multiple firings like you are experiencing.